# Optimization task in R (Integer values, SImplex)

Tags: r, optimization, integer, simplex

I have an optimization task. I use simples method, however my only question is how do I make X2, X4, X5 - integer and X1, X3, X6, X7 - any real numbers?

My current code is as follows:

```
    library(boot)
    a =c(6,10,2,1,6,7,1)
    A11= c(1,2,-15,12,-4,16,-6)
    A12 = c(-1,8,7,1,8,-1,1)
    A13 = c(4,-6,5,-3,5,5,2)
    A14 = c(3,5,2,-3,1,2,1)
    A15 = c(6,4,-5,3,5,3,5)
    A16 = c(-4,5,-4,5,4,5,4)
    b1 = c(150,100,110,157,166,140)
    A1 = rbind(A11, A12, A13,A14,A15,A16)
    simplex(a, A1, b1, maxi = TRUE)
```

Comment: You question is not clear to me. I suggest you clarify your question.